# SSAS TOM - how to access datasource for PowerBI model

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm using TOM to interrogate and manipulate a PBIX file open in Power BI.  The PBIX file uses a parameter to set the connection string to the sql database that sources the data for the model.  I cannot figure out how to return the datasource from the metadata for the file.  Here is the code I have:

```
//this all works fine
Server server = new Server(); //from Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular library
server.connect(connStr); //defined elsewhere
Model model = server.Databases[0].Model; //I am using this model to loop through tables and columns and it works fine

//these do not
model.DataSources
model.DataSources[0]
model.DataSources.find...

model.datasources.tostring() returns Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DataSourcesCollection
```

So it seems I have a collection, but trying to reference an item in the collection using DataSources[0] throws a parameter out of bounds error, which sort of makes sense in that the   DataSources.count property returns 0 (which seems wrong ->).  In looking at the datasources in the model via PowerBI desktop, the one I want is in there, fully formed with the database name filled from the parameter.

Can anyone give me a clue as to what's going on here or how I can get the datasource from the model?

Answer (score 1):

DataSources are used in SSAS proper, but not from Power BI Desktop models.

A Power BI model will only have Expressions and Partitions with M code in the **QueryDefinition** column. **Expressions** are Power Queries that aren't loaded to a table, and **Partitions** are Power Queries that are loaded directly to a table. You should find the connection info in one of these 2 places. You have to parse out connection info yourself from the query, unlike DataSources that have connection info in columns.

You can view all of this easily by installing the Tabular Editor v2 tool and launching it from the External Tools menu in Power BI. See [this page](https://docs.tabulareditor.com/te2/Advanced-Scripting.html) for details on its scripting capabilities.

**Launching Tabular Editor**
[image: Launching Tabular Editor]

**Object tree from Tabular Editor**
[image: Object tree from Tabular Editor]

**Shared Expression properties from Tabular Editor**
[image: Shared Expression properties from Tabular Editor]

Comment: Thank you very much!  Essentially I am trying to build out a templatized PBI solution that will require me to parameterize the connection string when deploying the solution on top of a given database.  It seems that the connection string is not accessible via TOM, which is a bummer, but the REST API does let you update parameters and is accessible via Powershell and the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt module.  I will try again with TOM first though since there are other manipulations to the model I need to make using that API.  Thanks again!

Comment: If you need to change the connection via parameters, it won't be like a connection string. For example, if you connect Power BI to a SSAS Tabular Database, the M code will be Source = AnalysisServices.Database(server_name, database_name, options). You absolutely can use another query or parameter to provide the server and database names. I do this all the time. Same goes for all other data types.

Comment: Thanks again.  I don't necessarily want to parameterize the entire connection string.  In fact in my initial (and current) design I only parameterize the database name.  I want to pass that parameter when I deploy the "template" version against a new database.  But TOM does not expose parameters as a collection.  So it seems I'm stuck with the REST API, which does have an update parameters endpoint in there somewhere.  PowerBI Dev Camp has an example.